# IF-statements producing errors in isolated cases

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using the following AMPscript to set variables and to allow fallback values if data isn't available for a Guardian.

```
%%[ 
SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey) 
SET @row = row(@rows,1) 
SET @firstName = field(@row,"firstName") 
SET @He_She__c = field(@row,"He_She__c") 
SET @Guardian_First_Name__c = field(@row,"Guardian_First_Name__c") 
IF NOT EMPTY(@Guardian_First_Name__c) THEN ]
%% Dear %%=v(@Guardian_First_Name__c)=%%,
%%[ELSE]%% Hello,%%
[ENDIF]%%
```

It works in 99% of cases, but I've just noticed that it triggers an error in 1% of cases when testing some new data.

I get this error:

> Invalid index (parameter 2) passed to Row function. Index must be less
>   than or equal to the row count. Index Value: 1 Row Count: 0 Function:
>   row(@rows,1)

Can anyone shed any light on this?  To my simple brain, this seems like an error that should happen in all cases, not a select few.

Comment: This error means that the subscriber (who triggered this error) is not found in `Contact_Salesforce` data extension. Is it possible that those who got the error are Leads or did not origin from Salesforce at all?

Comment: Thank you, in that case this is nothing for me to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend explicitly checking the [**rowcount**](https://ampscript.guide/rowcount) as a defensive measure. You could also do a [**raiseError()**](https://ampscript.guide/raiseerror) in an `ELSE` to skip the send to the subscriber.

```html
%%[ 

SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey) 

set @firstName = ""
set @He_She__c = ""
set @Guardian_First_Name__c = ""

if rowcount(@rows) > 1 then 

    SET @row = row(@rows,1) 
    SET @firstName = field(@row,"firstName") 
    SET @He_She__c = field(@row,"He_She__c") 
    SET @Guardian_First_Name__c = field(@row,"Guardian_First_Name__c") 

endif

IF NOT EMPTY(@Guardian_First_Name__c) THEN 

]%% 

Dear %%=v(@Guardian_First_Name__c)=%%,

%%[ ELSE ]%% 

Hello,

%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```